# Can't use mqueue properly

Tags: c, posix

I am trying to understand how to use `mqueue.h` to communicate between threads for work. I am aware that `mqueue.h` was designed for process communication and not threads, but it is the only posix queue API I could find, since I cannot use external libraries.

I have written this test code but, for some reason, the value received is different than the value sent. The purpose of this code is to send a pointer to another thread.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

typedef struct {
    mqd_t id;
    char* name;
} thread_data;

struct mq_attr attr = {0, 10, sizeof(char*), 0};

void *new_thread(void *arg) {
    char* pArg;
    thread_data *pData;
    int res;

    printf("Waiting to receive message (queue %d)...\n", *(mqd_t*)arg);
    fflush(stdout);
    res = mq_receive(*(mqd_t*)arg, pArg, sizeof(char*), NULL);

    if (res != -1)
    {
        pData = (thread_data*)pArg;
        printf("Message received in %p: %s\n", pData, pData->name);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Failed! errno = %d\n", errno);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t t1;
    thread_data data;

    data.name = "/thread1";
    data.id = mq_open(data.name, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0600, &attr);

    printf("Sending message %p (size %ld bytes)\n", &data, sizeof(char*));
    mq_send(data.id, (char*)&data, sizeof(char*), 0);
    printf("Message sent (queue %d).\n", data.id);

    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, new_thread, &data.id);
    pthread_join(t1, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

The output looks something like this:

```
$ ./a.out
Sending message 0x7ffd1c63eb20 (size 8 bytes)
Message sent (queue 3).
Waiting to receive message (queue 3)...
Message received in 0x7f5a92279700:
```

I'm hoping someone here can explain why this is happening, as I've spent quite some time on this.

Comment: `(char*)&data, sizeof(char*)` Why `sizeof(char*)`? `size 8 bytes` Why not send the whole structure?

Comment: @KamilCuk As I said, this is for work and the real structure is much larger, so I need to pass the pointer for the sake of efficiency

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Per your request, I've added the necessary `#include` directives.

Comment: I think you need another level of indirection in the send: `mq_send() adds the message _pointed to_ by msg_ptr` (my emphasis)

Comment: mq_receive needs an allocated buffer, you just pass in a random pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the correct level of indirection in your code, both in the send as well as the receive part.

Your `mq_send()` call sends the first 8 bytes of the **contents** of the structure whose pointer you are trying to send. Your `mq_receive()` call tries to store the data in an uninitialized pointer.

To fix the send part:

```c
    thread_data data;
    thread_data* ptr = &data;

    /* ... code ... */
    mq_send(data.id, (char*)&ptr, sizeof(thread_data*), 0);
    /* ... other code ... */
```

Note the `&ptr` here -- you are trying to send the value `ptr` (which itself is a pointer, but that's immaterial here), which means that you have to pass a pointer to that value to `mq_send`.

In the receive part, you'll have to change it as follows:

```c
    /* drop the pArg stuff */
    res = mq_receive(*(mqd_t*)arg, (char*)&pData, sizeof(thread_data*), NULL);
    if (res == sizeof(thread_data*)) {
        /* print pData-> ... */
    } else {
        /* error handling */
    }
```

Again, you want to receive the value `pData` here, so you have to pass a pointer to that value to `mq_receive`. Don't specify the pointer directly, that just means access to uninitialized memory.

To make this a bit clearer, let's say you wanted to send an integer, then you'd need the following code:

```c
/* plus initialize the queue with sizeof(int) */
int x = 42;
mq_send(data.id, (char*)&x, sizeof(int), 0);
/* and in the receive part */
int y = 0;
res = mq_receive(*(mqd_t*)arg, (char*)&y, sizeof(int), NULL);
```

Since you want to send a pointer instead of an integer, the change is in the type of the variable and the size passed to the mq functions - but in both cases you do pass `(char*)&variable` to the mq methods. Whether the variable holds an integer or a pointer is immaterial.

Comment: `sizeof(thread_data*)` Why not `sizeof(thread_data)`? I would prefer `sizeof(pData)`

Comment: Sure, `sizeof(pData)` will work fine, too, but that is the same as `sizeof(thread_data*)`, because that's the data type of the `thread_data` variable. `sizeof(thread_data)` will **not** work because that's the size of the structure `pData` points to, but not the size of the `pData` variable. In this example the OP wanted to transfer a *pointer*, so the size we transfer is the pointer. Of course you could also use mqueue to transfer a struct, but then the variable and size you'd use would be the struct, and not a pointer to the struct.